# Proving limits via episilon-delta definition vs. algebraic manipulation.

Tags: real-analysis, soft-question

In real analysis textbooks, limits are proved using the epsilon-delta definition directly. However, at some point, limits start being solved using algebraic manipulation. For example:
$$\lim_{x \to 5}\frac{x^2 - 25}{x-5} = \lim_{x \to 5}\frac{(x-5)(x+5)}{x-5}=\lim_{x \to 5}{x+5}=10$$

Is solving limits via algebraic manipulation still considered a rigorous proof?

Answer (score 1):

The manipulation rules are proven by epsilon-delta arguments, so everything always boils down to epsilon-delta in the end.  Depending on your calculus teacher, they may or may not ever really go through that.

Answer (score 1):

It is still rigorous, if you state it accurately. Suppose we rewrite $f(x)$ defined for $x\neq a$ as $f(x)=g(x)$ for all $x\neq a$. Then if $g(a)=b$ AND $g(x)$ is continuous at $x=a$, we may conclude:
$$
\lim_{x\to a} f(x)=g(a)=b
$$

---

The reason is, that since $g(x)$ is continuous at $x=a$, we have given $\varepsilon>0$ that we can find $\delta>0$ so that for $0<|x-a|<\delta$ we have
$$
|f(x)-b|=|g(x)-b|<\varepsilon
$$
and the conclusion follows. The continuity of $g(x)$ at $x=a$ plays a major role here.

---

In your example, we have
$$
f(x)=\frac{x^2-25}{x-5}
$$
equal to the continuous function $g(x)=x+5$ for all $x\neq a=5$. By continuity of $g$, the limit of $f$ agrees with the function value of $g$ at $x=5$.

Answer (score 0):

> Is solving limits via algebraic manipulation still considered a rigorous proof?

Yes. These are equivalent ways to show that a statement is true. There's no "most rigorous" way to prove a limit: fiddling with epsilons and deltas can feel very rigorous (hint: *technical* does not mean *rigorous*), but it results in a proof just as true as one that comes out of a single, elegant insight, or one that comes out of a sequence of algebraic manipulations.

There are many ways of proving limits -- depending on the problem, some of these ways will be more conducive to arriving at a swift or rigorous solution than others. Don't worry about picking the proof technique that you consider the most rigorous -- pick the one that allows you most easily and clearly to prove the statement.